# Магия HTML почему при значение больше height: 100vh появляется горизонтальный скролл

Tags: css3, html5

Столкнулся с проблемой при создании пустого пректа, решил указать height: 200vh
и получил проблему что появляется горизонтальный скролл, если выставлять значения 100 и меньше все окей, но если хоть на 1px больше, все ломается, что это такое?

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>s</title>
    <link href="css/reset.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/e44c60444d.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Lato:wght@300;400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="wrapper">

    </div> <!--wrapper-->
</body>

<script src="script/jquery-3.6.0.js"></script>
<script src="script/main_script.js"></script>
<!--<script src="script/scroll_up.js"></script> -->

</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
  font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
  background-color: #fdfdfd;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 200vh;
}
```

REST.CSS

```
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
    display: block;
}

body {
    line-height: 1;
}

ol,
ul {
    list-style: none;
}

blockquote,
q {
    quotes: none;
}

blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}

table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Comment: Пропишите margin:0 для body

Comment: Я не упомянул, но у меня подключен reset.css где все это прописанно и так-же box-sizing: border-box;

Comment: тогда приложите полный код, чтобы вашу ситуацию было возможно воспроизвести

Comment: Большая высота приводит к появлению вертикального сколлбара, этот скроллбар отъедает немного ширины страницы, и из-за этого отъедания 100vw перестаёт влезать в страницу и это приводит к появлению горизонтального скроллбара

Comment: И вообще width здесь абсолютно лишний, если его просто убрать, то горизонтальный скролл пропадает

Comment: И правда звучит логично, но как-то не догадался, лучше тогда просто использовать width: 100% и тогда его нету! Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

`100vh` он берет значение 'окна просмотра' и `100vw`  он берет значение 'окна просмотра  (то есть `vh`- height а `vw`- width).

подробнее: https://doka.guide/css/vw-vh/